# как найти максимальную разницу между двумя соседними элементами массива?

Tags: c++

Написал код, создал динамический массив , по заданию нужно указать максимальную разность между двумя соседними элементами массива и выделить при выводе эти элементы красным цветом.

Я покрасил только максимальную разность например если у нас есть такие числа: 1 3 2 6 - максимальная разность будет 4. Как мне покрасить два числа где находится это разность, в данном случае 2 и 6 -их и нужно покрасить.

Вот код :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


void massiv(int* x, int n)//функция заполнения и изменения 
{
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)//заполнение массива
{

    *(x+i) = rand() % 10;


    cout << *(x+i) << " ";

}
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, (WORD)((7 << 4) | 4));
int id = 0; // id - первый элемент пары, дающей максимальную разность

for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)

    if (abs(x[i] - x[i + 1]) > abs(x[id] - x[id + 1]))
    {

        id = i;

    }

cout << endl;
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, (WORD)((7 << 4) | 4));
cout << abs(x[id + 1] - x[id]);

}

int main()
{
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, (WORD)((7 << 4) | 0));
system("cls");
srand(time(NULL));
int n;
while (!(cin >> n)) //проверка на число
{
    cin.clear();
    while (cin.get() != '\n');
    cout << "NEVERNII VVOD" << endl;
}
if (n <= 0 || n == 1)
{
    cout << "Vvedite zanogo";
    cin >> n;
}
int* x = new int[n]; //динамическая переменная, выделение памяти


massiv(x, n);//вызов функции
cout << "\n";
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, (WORD)((7 << 4) | 0));
cout << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;

};
```

Comment: Как покрасить - SetConsoleTextAttribute. Задали цвет - выводите на экран. А в чём же таки проблема?

Comment: Не могу покрасить два числа, где разность

Comment: а зачем красить числа ???

Comment: @timob256 преподаватель сказал

Comment: Наверное Сколково... Некрашенные числа непрезентабельно смотрятся.

Comment: А ЗАЧЕМ ???? что это такого даст вам ?? Зачем для этого компьютер )) , я бы просто  от "чистого сердца" подарил бы ему раскраску :3 (такой талант пропадает )

Comment: @timob256 ну я покрасил рез-т , сказали что нужно покрасить два значения где между ними эта разность.

Comment: @timob256 в том то и проблема, она женщина

Comment: @timob256 форматирование и стилизация вывода - вполне себе прикладная задача при написании консольных приложений, не надо так болезнено реагировать.

Comment: *Не могу покрасить два числа*  - что именно мешает? Сформулиройте вопрос правильно. Где числа на экран выводятся извесно? Ставите проверку if  (условная покраска, так же?) и красьте себе. Неизвесно - учите матчасть.

Comment: @nick_n_a не знаю как , знаю как результат на выходе ( я его покрасил)

Comment: _Id = i;_ попробуй туда две переменных ввести , одна с значением i ,а другая с значением i+1

Answer (score 0):

Я как понял основная проблема это в алгоритме. *Подкрашивать цифры я не умею ;_;*

НО я могу предоставить логарифм :3  **ВОТ :**

```
int main()
{
    int massiw[] = {2,4,5,6,8,2,6,8,9,7,3,1};

    // вот алгоритм поиска двух ближайших чисел которые привели к самой большой разнице
    int datchik_t1 = 0;  int bigg_chislo = 0;// самая большая разница
     int chislo_1 = 0; // первое число давшее самую большую разницу
     int chislo_2 = 0; // второе число давшее самую большую разницу

    for(int i=0;i<(sizeof(massiw)/sizeof(int));i++){
        printf("  : %d \n", i);
        datchik_t1 = massiw[i]-massiw[i+1];
        if(datchik_t1<0) // меняем знак на противоположный
            datchik_t1 = datchik_t1*(-1);
        if(datchik_t1>bigg_chislo){
            bigg_chislo = datchik_t1;  
            chislo_1 =i;  chislo_2 = i+1;
        }
    }

    printf(" самое большое число : %d \n", bigg_chislo);
    printf(" два числа \"преведших\" к большому числу   : первое число - %d второе число - %d \n", massiw [chislo_1], massiw [chislo_2]);
    printf(" места в массиве занимают :  %d и %d \n", chislo_1+1, chislo_2+1); // плюс один чтоб перевести в "человеческие нормы" комп счититает с нуля 

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @mkkik увы, я не знаю как красить **буковы ;_;**

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @AlexBlack у тебя задачу можно разбить на две цели . Первая это математическая , то бишь логарифм . Вторая это админская ,это как раз подрисовка буковок (в линуксе к примеру потребуется подключить другие библиотеки) так что спрашивай вопросы, если есть.